# Layer switcher triggered by HTML button in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

in this code you have an example of layer switcher use in OpenLayers

https://rawgit.com/walkermatt/ol-layerswitcher/master/examples/layerswitcher.html

The button which triggers the action is written in .js using ol.control.LayerSwitcher, though.

```
var layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
    tipLabel: 'Légende' // Optional label for button
});
map.addControl(layerSwitcher);
```

What do I have to change if I want the same pop-up to be displayed, but by clicking the HTML icon in the "navbar" div of the site, not this button?

Answer (score 2):

To display or hide from your own code use

```
layerSwitcher.showPanel();
layerSwitcher.hidePanel();
```